# How do I make elements on a page fade in as I scroll down?

Tags: css, scroll

How do I make elements on a page fade in as I scroll down? Is there a way to do this using CSS only? I don't have knowledge in Javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t think there is actually a pure css way to do that. But it is quite easily using jQuery. Take a look at this fiddle:
      http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qad/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

Create a CSS class in order to make it work.

```
.hideme {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

And then apply this class to whatever element you want the effect.

Comment: Do I just create a jQuery file with that code and add it into my root folder? How does the code connect to the jQuery file?

Comment: @lagertha281 jQuery is technically Javascript. So the same way you would add a Javascript file to a page. You would also need to add a link to the jQuery api

Comment: You should include jQuery library js file via script tag and do the same with the code I provided. W3c schools provide more information on that:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp